# Announcing upcoming (Wednesday November 30) R&D Q&A on symbolic calculus development

Tags: support, feature-request

Devendra Kapadia and I are looking forward to hosting the “Q&A with Calculus & Algebra Developers" tomorrow (Wednesday) at 11:00 CT. This follows the "[What's new in Calculus & Algebra](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2596451)" from this past August. For ways to participate please visit [the Wolfram Community post announcing the Wolfram R&D livestreams series](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2593151).

We will begin by giving a glimpse of recent and upcoming features in symbolic calculus, many of which have been motivated by frequent requests from users. You will then have an opportunity to ask questions related to the evaluation of integrals, sums, differential equations, limits and pretty much anything else that falls within the scope of this discussion.

We will also welcome any suggestions for symbolic computation enhancements in future releases.

We look forward to (virtually) seeing you at the Q&A.

Comment: (+1) Is this an invitation to share questions here too? Or, is it only live questions? I'm thinking about what happened before [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2693/10397).

Comment: @rhermans You can post them here. But I think the better place to post questions in advance would be in the Wolfram Community thread, under the announcement by Devendra Kapadia. Time and my flaky memory permitting, I will check here before we start, but the Community thread is monitored by more people. (That stated, we perhaps should have created a separate thread for this.)